# Problem with changing color of label in checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, input, label

I'm doing a quiz using HTML and JavaScript. Right now, I am trying to do  questions that have more than one answer using checkboxes. When you answer incorrectly, the answer that you have chosen should appear in red and the correct one in green. I tried doing that using this code:

**JavaScript**

```js
if ( document.getElementById('doc').checked && 
   document.getElementById('prompt').checked &&
   document.getElementById('get').checked &&
   document.getElementById('alert').checked
) {
   document.getElementById("label33").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("label34").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("label35").style.color = 'green';
   document.getElementById("label36").style.color = 'green';
   pkt+=2;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pytanie14</legend>
    <p>Jakimi sposobami można wyświetlić tekst? (Uwaga.Może być więcej niż jedna odpowiedź).</p>

    <label for="doc" id="label33"><input type="checkbox" id="doc"/>document.write("tekst");</label>
    <br>
    <label for="prompt" id="label34"><input type="checkbox" id="prompt"/>prompt("tekst");</label>
    <br>
    <label for="get" id="label35"><input type="checkbox" id="get"/>document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="tekst";</label>
    <br>
    <label for="alert" id="label36"><input type="checkbox" id="alert"/>alert("tekst");</label>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

With this code when I check all the checkboxes only one (the last answer) appears in green and the others are in red. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: we need all of the code (inkl. button to send the data)

Comment: i can send it but it has more than 1000 lines

Comment: hmm... do it in a codesnipping tool like playcode.io